# Electron,React Desktop app :- Unable to access local file dialog

Tags: reactjs, electron, electron-builder

I am using electron builder to convert web app to desktop app for linux.
my electron.js file consist code

```
const electron = require("electron");
const { app, BrowserWindow } = electron;
const path = require("path");
const isDev = require("electron-is-dev");

let mainWindow = null;
app.on("ready", createWindow);
app.on("window-all-closed", function () {
  if (process.platform !== "darwin") {
    app.quit();
  }
});
app.on("activate", function () {
  if (mainWindow === null) {
    createWindow();
  }
});
function createWindow() {
  mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 1024,
    height: 1024,
    title: "my app",
    autoHideMenuBar: true,
    webPreferences: {
      devTools: false, // Disable developer tools
    },
  });

  mainWindow.loadURL(isDev ? "http://localhost:3000" : `file://${path.join(__dirname, "../build/index.html")}`);
  mainWindow.on("closed", function () {
    mainWindow = null;
  });

  mainWindow.on("page-title-updated", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
  });
}
```

in package.json i have

```
 "build": {
    "appId": "com.myapp.app",
    "linux": {
      "executableName": "myapp",
      "desktop": {
        "StartupNotify": "false",
        "Encoding": "UTF-8",
        "MimeType": "x-scheme-handler/deeplink"
      },
      "target": [
        "AppImage",
        "rpm",
        "deb"
      ],
      "icon": "public/256x256.png",
      "category": "Video"
    } ,}
```

i have myapp.deb file which are running fine in some desktop of linux,
but in some systems when i am clicking on browse file button, it is not resulting anything,not opening file upload dialog from local,
in my app.tsx file i have this code to upload file

```
 <input id="files" type="file" onChange={(e)=>{console.log(e.target.files[0])}} />
```

unable to open local file upload dialog.

Comment: You need to use the Dialog API in the main process: https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/dialog and then you can send the contents of the file back to the FE using the built-in IPC.